# Why does stack pop off ( and not +

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm writing a code that converts infix to postfix for a hw assignment. 
I've debugged it but I can't seem to work out why when it pops off the stack it returns '(' instead of '+'

```
 StackInterface<Character> stack = new ArrayStack<Character>();
      String postfix = "";
      int length = infxEx.length();
       for(int i =0; i != length; ++i){

          char oneChar =infxEx.charAt(i);  
         if(oneChar == '('){
            stack.push(oneChar);
          }else
         if(oneChar == '*' || oneChar == '/'|| oneChar == '%'|| oneChar == '+' || oneChar == '-'){
           stack.push(oneChar);
         //error checking input is int
         }
         else if(oneChar == ')'){
           while (stack.pop() != '(' && !stack.empty()){

           char popoff =  stack.pop();
           postfix = postfix + popoff; 
         }
         }
```

Thank You!

Comment: Adding the input that allows us to reproduce the problem would be nice.

Comment: This algorithm is not correct. It doesn't handle operator precedence. You need to look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop to handle reaching a `)`, you pop twice from the stack for each element you check (first in the while condition to check `stack.pop() != '('` and again within the body of the loop to grab `popoff`, so you will lose about half of the characters; since this is triggered by reaching a `)` in the main loop, and since you are ignoring anything that isn't an operator (so your stack for `(a + b)` would contain `(+`, and you would strip off the `+` while checking for `(`, which means you will add the `(` to your postfix within the `while` loop body, and terminate the loop when the stack is empty instead.

Use a peek operation to look at the top of the stack without actually removing the value in your while loop condition to solve that problem, and if you accept tokens other than operators in your infix expressions, you will need an `else` clause to handle that case also.